# find the point with the maximum third element in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Dear all: if I have an array, let's say

```
a=np.asarray([[1,1,2],[2,3,1]])
```

is there any way to find the point with the greatest third element. For example, in this case, I want the code to return the second point which is [1,1,2].

Then what about the greatest second element which should return [2,3,1]

thanks a lot for your great help and advice.

Comment: `max(a, key=lambda e:e[2])`?

Comment: @Chris, sorry for my wording. the first point is [1,1,2] and the second point is [2,3,1]. so the greatest third element is in point 1 which is 2

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Green Cloak Guy, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more *numpythonic* (than in one of comments) way to get the answer,
for any element of interest, is:

```
elemNo = 1
a[np.argmax(a[:, elemNo])]
```

Note that:

- `a[:, elemNo]` retrieves the column of interest,
- `np.argmax(...)` finds the index of the max value in this column.

So `a[...]` retrieves the whole row with just this index.

This solution should also work faster than *map / lambda*, what can
be important especially for bigger arrays.